# Communicate between two docker containers

Tags: docker

I’m newbie about docker and i need your help about communicate between containers.

I have two containers
Container 1: it is a Website and runs on port 80
Container 2: it is a web API of above Website and runs on port 8000

I install two containers in my Raspberry Pi. my RPi hostname is raspberrypi
I created two containers with --net=host so in my website, I can call my website via http://raspberrypi:8000/dosomething

but host name of RPi can be changed and I can’t recreate the website container with new API URL (for example: http//new_host_name:8000/dosomething) so my question is

is there any way to assign host name to a container so I can use it in other container ?
for example:
Container 2 uses “my_service” as its host name, so in Container 1 , I can use “http//my_service:8000/dosomething”. my customer can change their host name of RPI and I don’t need to update my codes.

Thanks and have nice day.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you run the first container with the following command:

```
docker run -d --name my_service web_api_image
```

so you can use the `--link` flag to run the second:

```
docker run -d -P --name web --link my_service:my_service website_image
```

then, within website container you can refer to the web api using my_service hostname.

please note:
`--link` is [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links).

you can also use `docker-compose`:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web_api:
    image: web_api_image
    container_name: web_api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
  website:
    image: website_image
    container_name: website
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - "web_api:web_api"
```

replace image names and run with `docker-compose up`

Comment: Thanks. but when I use --link, it displays an error message "docker: Error response from daemon: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior.
". maybe, I use --net=host. Anyway, can you give me an example about docker-compose in this case ?

Comment: don't use `--net` flag. make sure you removed all containers `docker ps -a`. If you prefer docker-compose I edit the answer..

Comment: @Doraemon so, can you please accept/upvote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker-compose`, since all containers within the same compose file are within the same network by default and can call each other using their service name.

However, if you are using `docker run` you can specify hostname using `-h` flag. Example: `docker run -h test.example.com -it ubuntu /bin/bash`.

I would recommend you to look into [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) of docker-compose. Further ahead, you and your customer, both can use a [`env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file) variable to specify values for variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use bridge driver network in docker to communicate between two containers.

The github sample in .net core 2.2 is [here](https://github.com/younos1986/DockerizedEventStoreSample)

```
version: '3.4'

services:
eventstoresample: 
  image: eventstoresample
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: EventStoreSample/Dockerfile
  networks:
    clusternetwork:
      ipv4_address: 172.16.0.12

eventstore: 
image: eventstore/eventstore
environment:
  - EVENTSTORE_INT_IP=172.16.0.13
  - EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PORT=2113
  - EVENTSTORE_EXT_TCP_PORT=1113
  - EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PREFIXES=http://*:2113/
ports:
  - "1113:1113"
  - "2113:2113"
networks:
  clusternetwork:
    ipv4_address: 172.16.0.13

networks:
  clusternetwork:
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    driver: default
    config:
      - subnet: 172.16.0.0/24
```